# Angularjs loading more than once. asp .net mvc project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using angular-routing in my asp .net mvc project here getting warning like  follows while passing parameters from mvc controller and displaying it on view where i want to pass user id from mvc. Can any one help me solve it and how to make it asynchronous?

```
"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because 
of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, 
check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
VM168:289WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."
```

[image]

**demoController.cs** (demo controller page)

```
public ActionResult WithParams(int? type)
    {
        ViewBag.Type = type;
        return View();
    }
```

**demo.cshtml** (view)

```
    @{ 
      ViewBag.Title = "WithParams"; 
       }

<h2>WithParams</h2>

@if(ViewBag.Type==1)
{
    <p>You passed 1</p>
}
else
{
    <p>You Passed 2</p>
}
```

**myapp.js** (angular)

```
    angular.module('app',['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider',  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/demo', {
        templateUrl: 'demo/demo',
        controller: 'demoCtrl'
      }). otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]).controller('dashCtrl' , function($scope){console.log("demo page")
}
```

Comment: Links to `localhost` only work on *your* machine. Inspect the HTML in the browser and see whether there are multiple `<script>` elements trying to load angular. If there are, you need to work out where they're coming from. Most of the code you've put in the question seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: Although you do add the code that shows the initialization of angularjs, this error is obviously to do with loading angular.js twice. You could have it in the `@scripts` section of the view and on the `_layout.cshtml` or maybe twice in the bundle.config. Hard to tell